# phpmyadmin error #2002 cannot connect to mysql server

Tags: mysql, php, socket

I am getting the error in the title when trying to connect to my MySQL server. I have reinstalled MySQL and PHP several times and tried a slew of command line work based on information I searched out.

`web.mysql` is running and I know that my `mysql.sock` exists and is located in `~/private/tmp/` and also in `~/tmp/`. I also have plenty of hard drive space. I have installed and setup phpMyAdmin correctly only adding a password to 'Password for config auth'. I have also connected to the server via Sequel Pro.

Why can't I connect to the server via phpMyAdmin? I'm on a 64-bit Intel Mac running Snow Leopard

Answer (score 1):

Make sure phpMyAdmin is not trying to look for *mysql.sock* in */var/lib/mysql/*. I had the same error yesterday and creating a link from */var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock* to */tmp/mysql.sock* fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes MySQL sets itself to only accept incoming on the loopback address (127.0.0.1). PHPMyAdmin is most likely trying to connect to "localhost".

You can change the my.cnf file to allow all connections to the MySQL server or modify the PHPMyAdmin config to point to 127.0.0.1. My suggestion would be to do the later in case of future upgrades.